# unable to authenticate with kerberos to ipa client from windows 10 machine

Tags: ssh, kerberos, freeipa, gssapi

I have a domain joined windows 10 computer trying to authenticate via kerberos to an ipa (4.4.0) client (centos 7.2), I can authenticate with user/pass and then kinit but I cannot seem to authenticate with the kerberos tickets on my machine.

ipaclients CAN authenticate via kerberos to windows servers (winrm).

Layout
example.org = trusted domain with users
example.com = root domain for systems
ad.example.com = child domain for systems
ipa.example.com = realm for FreeIPA

Authentication to all domains from users@example.org works, kerberos for things like IIS Windows Authentication works as expected, Winrm works from windows and linux using kerberos.  I have not tested apache 401 with keytabs and trusted users yet.

> debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
> debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
> unable to find realm of host WIN10HOSTNAME
>
> debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
> unable to find realm of host WIN10HOSTNAME
>
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

WIN10HOSTNAME = hostname

I've tried MIT Kerberos and also tried setting the default realm in the krb5.ini file (windows).  I'm not really sure how to set the default realm.

**Windows 10 Client (mingw64)**

`ssh -V`

> OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

`klist`

```
Current LogonId is 0:0x3a258

Cached Tickets: (4)

 1      Client: jevans @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        Server: krbtgt/AD.EXAMPLE.ORG @ EXAMPLE.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40a50000 -forwardable renewable pre_authent ok_as_delegate name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 1/26/2017 8:26:58 (local)
        End Time:   1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: DC01.example.com

 1      Client: jevans @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        Server: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40a50000 -forwardable renewable pre_authent ok_as_delegate name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 1/26/2017 8:26:58 (local)
        End Time:   1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: DC01.example.org

 2      Client: jevans @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        Server: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ORG @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e10000 -forwardable renewable initial pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 1/26/2017 8:25:47 (local)
        End Time:   1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0x1 -PRIMARY
        Kdc Called: DC01.example.org

 3      Client: jevans @ EXAMPLE.ORG
        Server: ldap/AD-DC01.AD.EXAMPLE.ORG/AD.EXAMPLE.ORG @ AD.EXAMPLE.ORG
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40a50000 -forwardable renewable pre_authent ok_as_delegate name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 1/26/2017 8:26:58 (local)
        End Time:   1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/26/2017 18:25:47 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: AD-DC01.ad.example.com
```

**Linux Endpoint**
`ktutils`, then `read_kt /etc/krb5.keytab`, then `list`

```
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   2    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   3    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   4    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   5    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   6    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   7    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   8    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
   9    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  10    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  11    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  12    1 host/linux-server@IPA.EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: please list an output of your keytab file - `ktutils`, then `read_kt /etc/krb5.keytab`, then `list`

Comment: I do not have either of those commands on my windows 10 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by trashing **mingw64** for **cygwin**.

mingw64 is clearly for minimalists and is missing the required kerberos packages (among many other great packages)

I was able to get cygwin to do not only Kerberos auth, but also [SSH Agent Keys](https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/Windows.html)